# Reactjs Attempted to update component that has already been unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a dashboard showing info in different views. These views can be toggled, i.e. the user should be able to pick the view/representation in a list and the page will show the relevant component for that view.

The code for this looks something like this:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        chartView: true,
        problemsByStatus: {
            chartValues: [],
            tableValues: []
        }
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadDashboardInfo();
};

toggleView() {
    this.setState({
        chartView: !this.state.chartView
    })
}

loadDashboardInfo() {
    $.getJSON("/api/problems").then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            problemsByStatus: data;
        })
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <div className="row">
                 <Toggle
                   className="pull-right"
                   onClick={() => this.toggleView()}
                   on={<span><i className='fa fa-pie-chart'></i> Pie chart</span>}          off={<span><i className='fa fa-table'></i> Table</span>}          size="sm"
                   active={this.state.chartView}
            />
            { this.state.chartView ?
                <div className="col-md-6 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-12 ">
                    <DoughnutChart data={this.state.problemsByStatus.chartValues} colorCodes={this.colorCodes} />
                </div>
                :
                <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <BootstrapTable data={this.state.problemsByStatus.tableValues}>

                    </BootstrapTable>
                </div>
            }
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}
```

}

With DoughnutChart just being a wrapper around the react-chartjs-2 module:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Chart, Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class DoughnutChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.colorCodes = props.colorCodes;

        this.state = {
            data: this.getDoughnutData(props.data)
        };

        var doughnutDraw = Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.draw;
        Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype, {
            draw: function() {
                doughnutDraw.apply(this, arguments);

                var chart = this.chart;
                var width = chart.chart.width,
                    height = chart.chart.height,
                    ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
                ctx.font = fontSize + "em Verdana";
                ctx.fillStyle = "#292b2c";
                ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
                    sum += chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[i];
                }

                var text = sum;
                var textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
                var textY = (height + 20) / 2;

                ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
            }
        });
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            data: this.getDoughnutData(nextProps.data)
        });
    }

    getDoughnutData(items) {
        var data = [];
        var labels = [];
        var backgroundColors = [];

        $.each(items, (_, item) => {
            data.push(item.count);
            labels.push(item.type);
            backgroundColors.push(this.colorCodes[item.type]);
        });

        return {
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColors
                }
            ],
            labels: labels
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Doughnut data={this.state.data}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, each time i'm switching the view (by changing the chartview state to false) and then switching it back, i get the exception:

```
Attempted to update component `DoughnutChart` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount).
```

A similar thing happens for the tableview i'm using. I suspect this has to do with the chartValues state that is being updated and still has a reference to the DougnutChart component, so it tries to rerender the component but it was already unmounted (since the tableview was activated). Is this correct? And if so, how would i handle this situation? I always read it was best to switch views in the render method itself, such that the components get unmounted and are not just hidden and needlessly updated. But for me, this causes the issue described above.

Comment: would be helpful to see the code of `DoughnutChart` component

Comment: DoughnutChart component has been added to the post. It's just a wrapper around the react-chartjs-2 module.